# Can I safely reduce CPU usage with kill -SIGSTOP?

Tags: linux, cpu, kill, signals

I have 7 differents workspaces and each of them have a different purpose.

But everything runs in the background... For exemple the workspace 5 with my browser is using CPU even when I'm on workspace 2. Which I find ridiculous. (I'm using a simple terminal and my cpu is at ~20% for some stupid JS running on another workspace.)

I'm using a script now to switch between workspaces, and it triggers a series of `kill -SIGSTOP $(pidof PROGRAM)` and `-SIGCONT` only the programs of the current workspace.

My CPU usage has decreased significantly, but are there any drawbacks of doing this?

Can a long term STOPPED process cause any trouble somehow?

Is there a more conventional way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Can avoid running many apps be an alternative? I usually only keep a couple of terminals and the web browser with 2-3 tabs at most.

Comment: I have a lot of them, but I still need them to be available instantly. I'm fine if they just wait in RAM but I can't let them change my overall system responsiveness. + laptop battery